# Is $\text{fix}_\Omega(G_\alpha)$ a block of imprimitivity when $G$ is infinite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, infinite-groups

> Let $G$ be an infinite transitive permutation group acting on a set $\Omega$. Is $\text{fix}_\Omega(G_\alpha)$ a block of imprimitivity for $G$ in $\Omega$?

---

$G_\alpha$ is the set of elements of $G$ that fix $\alpha \in \Omega$

$\text{fix}_\Omega(G_\alpha)$ is the set of points in $\Omega$ fixed by $G_\alpha$.

A block of imprimitivity for $G$ in $\Omega$ is a set $B\subseteq \Omega$ such that for any $g \in G$, $B^g=B$ or $B^g \cap B = \emptyset$

---

I can show this in the finite case where $\text{fix}_\Omega(G_\alpha) = \alpha^{N_G(G_\alpha)}$, the orbit of $\alpha$ under the normalizer of $G_\alpha$, but in the infinite case I'm not sure if this is still true.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false in general, because there are infinite groups $G$ containing a subgroup $H$ and an element $y$ such that $K := y^{-1}Hy$ is a proper subgroup of $H$. An example is the Baumslag-Solitar group $\langle x,y \mid y^{-1}xy = x^2 \rangle$ with $H = \langle x \rangle$. (This can also be defined as a $2 \times 2$ group of matrices over ${\mathbb Q}$.)

Consider the transitive permutation action by right multiplication on the right cosets of $H$ in $G$. Let $\alpha=H$ and $\beta=Hy$. Then $G_\alpha=H$ and $G_\beta = y^{-1}Hy=K$, so $G_\beta$ is a proper subgroup of $G_\alpha$. Hence ${\rm Fix}(G_\alpha)$ is a proper subset of ${\rm Fix}(G_\beta)$ (it contains $\alpha$ but not $\beta$). But $y^{-1}$ maps ${\rm Fix}(G_\beta)$ to ${\rm Fix}(G_\alpha)$, so ${\rm Fix}(G_\beta)$ cannot be a block.

Comment: I have a feeling this may be a silly question, but it seems as though you're first defining your set $\Omega$ to be the set of right cosets of $H$ and then considering it to be the set of conjugates of $H$, or perhaps I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, sorry I wrote it too quickly this morning - I was confusing two different actions. I hope it's clearer now!

Comment: That's much clearer but I'm not sure if your claim that $G_\beta = y^{-1} H y$ is justified in this case. I've gone through your example using $x=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ and $y =\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$. Hence $H=\{\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)\mid k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and $Hy=\{\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & k \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)\mid k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and $H$ seems to fix both of these sets.

Comment: In your example $y^{-1}Hy$ is a bigger than $H$, not smaller! You should replace $y$ by $y^{-1}$ to get $y^{-1}Hy < H$. It is not hard to prove in any permutation group that if $H=G_\alpha$ and $\alpha^y=\beta$, then $G_\beta = y^{-1}Hy$.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake indeed. I've recently been doing some work in which conjugation is in the opposite order. Thank you very much for your help. Great counterexample!